# Changing navigationControllers title from elsewhere

Tags: swift

I have a little problem.

Purely for troubleshooting purposes, I want `applicationDidBecomeActive()` to rename the current views navigationcontroller.

The class which houses the navbar is `wrapperviewController()`, so within that I can use `self.navigationItem.title = "Test"`, but I tried to do

`wrapperviewController().navigationItem.title = "Maybe?"` does not.

I tried `wrapperviewController().navigationController.navigationItem.title = "Maybe?"` as well.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation title is automatically set from the UINavigationController's top view controller, so you could do this:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    (window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController?.title = "My Debug Title"
}
```

This assumes the root is a UINavigationController. If you have some other wrapper, you can insert the appropriate unwrapping.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however, my question was more of an example, and I was hoping the answer would help the rest of my problems. I may post again with the full problem, until then I will mark yours as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing navigation bar title name from AppDelegate, In applicationDidBecomeActive() method, try below code:-

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationItem.title = "Title Name"
```

If you have multiple view controllers than you can check over there for view controller & assign a title.